# Setting up .htaccess rewrite rules for VUE-JS SPA

Tags: apache, .htaccess, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a VUE application that is using the VUE Router in History mode and can not seem to get it working on my production server. I have setup the .htaccess file using the settings given in the documentation:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

This seems to work fine for the front end; aka (www.url.com/Anything/anything) seems to get routed properly.

The issue comes when I am trying to route to my admin:

```
www.url.com/admin/dashboard
```

This is setup as route with a child route in my index.js but I think I need to set up something special in my .htaccess as well however I can't seem to find anything about how to do this. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What do you see at the `admin/dashboard` route?

Comment: I get a 404 error

Comment: Are you serving the app at the root of the domain? And what do you mean by "www.url.com/Anything/anything seems to get routed properly" if the admin route is not being routed properly?

Comment: So I found out it was a setting on the server by the host that they had to give me permission to create an htaccess file. Spent days pulling my hair out and they just flipped a switch and it worked.

Comment: @user10012 could you share your solution for this one? thank you

Comment: I have posted the contents of the htaccess file that is currently working for me. Unfortunately I'm not sure what the exact change was that made the difference because my hosting company did it for me,  but hopefully it will work for you also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what my hosting company changed my .htaccess file to that worked for me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://myURL.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Comment: Can someone explain where to put this file in a vue.js app? Do I need to put it into the created dist/build directory ?

Comment: It does not go in the vue.js app its a text file that should be in the folder where you are serving your compiled vue app from. Probably the root web folder. I think the apache default is var/www/html